# Terraform .12 InvalidSubnetID.NotFound

Tags: terraform0.12+

I have two public Subnets declared in my VPC and now I want to create an EC2 instance in each of the two public subnets, but Terraform doesn't properly resolve the subnet ids

Here is what I have defined:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "archer-public-1" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.archer.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.1.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"
  availability_zone       = "${var.AZ1}"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "archer-public-2" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.archer.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.2.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"
  availability_zone       = "${var.AZ2}"
}
```

Here is my EC2 resource definition with the subnet expression that I tried unsuccessfully.

```
resource "aws_instance" "nginx" {
  count = 2
  ami           = var.AMIS[var.AWS_REGION]
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = "aws_subnet.archer-public-${count.index+1}.id"  <== why doesn't this work?!
}
```

The variable interpolation does produce the proper values for the two subnets:  archer-public-1 and archer-public-2, yet, the terraform produces these errors:

```
Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidSubnetID.NotFound: The subnet ID 'aws_subnet.archer-public-1.id' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 26b4f710-e968-484d-a17a-6faa5a9d15d5
```

Yet when I invoke the *terraform console*, I can see that it properly resolves these objects as expected:

```
> aws_subnet.archer-public-1
{
  "arn" = "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:361879417564:subnet/subnet-0fb47d0d30f501585"
  "assign_ipv6_address_on_creation" = false
  "availability_zone" = "us-west-2a"
  "availability_zone_id" = "usw2-az1"
  "cidr_block" = "10.0.1.0/24"
  "id" = "subnet-0fb47d0d30f501585"
  "ipv6_cidr_block" = ""
  "ipv6_cidr_block_association_id" = ""
  "map_public_ip_on_launch" = true
  "outpost_arn" = ""
  "owner_id" = "361879417564"
  "tags" = {
    "Name" = "archer-public-1"
  }
  "vpc_id" = "vpc-074637b06747e227b"
}
```

Comment: I tried this expression:  subnet_id = "aws_subnet.archer-public-1.id" and it didn't work either...    So I removed the double-quotes and then it worked.    However, the interpolation doesn't work without double-quotes, so what should this expression be?